# In a kaggle notebook, how to show all hidden code cells (Show hidden code) at once?

Tags: javascript, console, kaggle

Follow [this notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/kellibelcher/amex-default-prediction-eda-lgbm-baseline) as example, is it possible to inject a javascript code into the browser console for all cells to be visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the notebook page, go to the Chrome Console tab (F12) and paste the code below.
Invisible cells have the class "sc-jSMfEi imrMBR".
The code identifies each one and clicks on them to make them visible.

```
list_hiddencode = document.getElementsByClassName("sc-jSMfEi imrMBR");
for (var i =0; i < list_hiddencode.length; i++){
   list_hiddencode[i].click();
}
```